# CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Missing

Tags: html, cors

I am facing an issue with my hosted project.

The request with link :- http://......./api_tester.html works fine and
provides results, but, it gives `CORS  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Missing`
 when the `api_tester.html` file is accessed via the browser directly.

The URL for the file in the browser is `file:///E:/workspace_windows/api_tester.html`

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to open the file directly from desktop, hence it is picking its protocol file:// protocol. Use either complete url starting with HTTP or run from any web server. Secondly error you stated means you are trying to access the page hosted on another domain and this usually happens when you do XHR requests to domain other than the one where your file is hosted.

You can add header "ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN" to the file you are trying to access to allow all requests to be accessible from all different domains.

Comment: I did add that Header you mentioned now the error is changed to "CORS preflight channel did not succeed" Any Idea about that